What is the asymptotic bias of the nonparametric histogram density estimator?
I am trying to derive an expression for the asymptotic bias of the nonparametric histogram density estimator in order to compare it to the bias of the kernel density estimator. In terms of notation, given sample $(x_i)^n_{i=1}$ and a point $x \in \mathbb{R}$, the histogram is defined by $\hat{h}(x)=(nl_n)^{-1}\sum^n_{i=1}I(a_n\leq x\leq b_n)$ where $l_n=b_n-a_n$ and $I$ denotes the indicator function (maybe this is trivial, but I am not too familiar with the matter). I have received a hint, which states that I need to assume the existence of limits $(a_n - x)/l_n$ and $(b_n-x)/l_n$.
Thus far, I have expressed the expectation of the estimate as:
$E[\hat{h}(x)]=(l_n)^{-1}Pr(a_n\leq x\leq b_n)$. Then, I use Taylor expansion around $x$ to obtain:
$f(u)\approx f(x)+f'(x)(u-x)$.
So I write,
$$E[\hat{h}(x)]=(l_n)^{-1}Pr(a_n\leq x\leq b_n) \approx (l_n)^{-1}\int^{b_n}_{a_n} f(x)+f'(x)(u-x)du$$
However, here I am stuck. I can guess that integrating the first term ($f(x)$) on the boundaries yields $\int^{b_n}_{a_n}f(x)du=f(x)l_n$, due to the relationship between $b_n$, $a_n$, and $l_n$. Then, the $l_n$ cancels out, and $f(x)$ remains. This is the true value of the density, so I think that integrating the second term ($\int^{b_n}_{a_n} f'(x)(u-x)du$) must constitute the bias.
Have I used the assumption on the existence of limits? How can I work out the second term in the integral? I would like to be able to compare it to the kernel estimate, which equals $\frac{h^2}{2}f''(x)\mu_2(K)$. Is there a representation of this second term (can I develop it further), to be able to do so?
By the way, I am aware that I have omitted the $O(.)$ from the Taylor expansion (for the sake of ease).
I'd be very thankful if somebody could help me. Thank you in advance!

" I need to assume the existence of limits..." That makes little sense to me. Limit with respect of what? $x$ is a fixed value there? Notation is confusing. THe summation has an $i$ index which does not appear inside. Also your histogram should be a random value, and that is not apparent in your formula.

Thank you for your answer. I have added the sample information such that the index $i$ hopefully makes more sense. Concerning the limit, here is the literal quote: 'You need to assume the existence of limits $(a_n − x)/l_n
and (b_n − x)/l_n$'. I am not sure about its significance to the problem either. However, even without this assumption, I am still not able to find an expression for the asymptotic bias I can use to compare with the kernel density estimator.
